# Persisting entity relationships from REST service for Android

Tags: android, spring, jackson, ormlite, robospice

I am trying to maintain a local store of a database, accessible via a REST API. I am attempting to use the fantastic RoboSpice and Spring libraries for the REST client, Jackson to parse/cache the JSON response and ORMLite to persist the resulting objects.

The problem is that I don't know how to store foreign object relationships for the JSON responses I get. Sometimes the JSON objects are nested, other times they are referenced by Id.

A typical systems response

```
{
    id:567,
    name:"The only system",
    competitions:[{
         id:123,
         system_id:567
         ...
    }];
}
```

A competitions response

```
items: {
    123:{
        id:123,
        system_id:567 // System only referenced by id
        ...
    }}
```

Another competitions response

```
items: {
    123:{
        id:123,
        system_id:567, // System referenced by id and nested
        system:{
            id:567,
            name:"The only system",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Nested objects work fine, but it's the cases where there is a reference by id that is killing it. I have two classes for my data model as follows.

Systems class

```
@DatabaseTable("systems")
public class System {
     @JsonProperty("id")
     @DatabaseField(id=true, columnName="id")
     private long id;

     @JsonProperty("name")
     @DatabaseField(columnName="name")
     private String name;

     @JsonProperty("competitions")
     @ForeignCollectionField
     private ForeignCollection<Competition> competitions;

     // getters & setters omitted
}
```

Competition class

```
@DatabaseTable("competitions")
public class Competition {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @DatabaseField(id=true,columnName="id")
    private long id;

    @JsonProperty("system_id")
    @DatabaseField(columnName="id")
    private long systemId; // This is definitely at least part of the problem

    @JsonProperty("system")
    @DatabaseField(foreign=true, columnName="system_id")
    private System system;

    // getters & setters omitted

}
```

Having two properties references the system_id seems like a definitively bad idea, but I can't find an alternative for the behaviour I want. Even if the system object is not nested in the Competition object, the Competition should be able to map a relationship to the System object in the local database, because the id of the system is always provided.

The other problem I suspect is that I'm using two object persisters, the JacksonObjectPersister and the InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory (provided by RoboSpice for use with ORMLite). The reason for this is because I don't want to persist the lists that the objects are nested in to the database. By my understanding, Jackson should cache the JSON response from the server, ORMLite should cache the data model.

This is the error I'm getting

```
02-03 15:15:57.640: D//DefaultRequestRunner.java:166(20944): 15:15:57.636 Thread-28 
An exception occurred during service execution :org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:(was java.lang.NullPointerException) 
(through reference chain: com.company.app.api.objects.List["items"]->
java.util.HashMap["51"]->
com.company.app.api.objects.Competition["system_id"])
```

Apologies for what seems like a number of questions in one, I am bashing my head against a wall. I will attempt to wrap this essay up with a summary...

**Is there any way to piece together object relationships using Jackson and ORMLite for the JSON responses I have provided?**